# $.get doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It tried to run the following code:

```
$.get({
    url: '/proxy/playing',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Data received: ' + data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log('Error occured!');
    }
});
```

It never reaches `success` or `error`. I tried everything, using `$.ajax` or `XmlHttpRequest`. In all scenario's no success or error callbacks are being called. I just don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

These article's I based my code on:

- [Docs $.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
- [Docs $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [Docs XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Do you see request in the network activity tab of the browser's developer's tools (press F12 for it)? Or do you see any error messages in the console there?

Comment: Are you sure execution is reaching the line that calls `$.get` in the first place?

Comment: `$.get()` only supports the success/done callback, unless you attach deferred objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are switching signatures, instead you should have :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/proxy/playing',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Data received: ' + data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log('Error occured!');
    }
});
```

If you want to make use of $.get shorthand then :

```
$.get('/proxy/playing', function(data){
    console.log('Data received: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: And what method does `ajax` use by default?

Comment: AJAX uses GET by default.